# On signout access denied message is thrown in sharepoint

Tags: active-directory, forms-authentication

I created a loginpage using FBA and Active Directory Authentication. It is working fine when I am trying to login. 
But when I try to signout it is showing layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx in the url .
Kindly help me solve this problem.